# Issue about vertical text alignment in UITableViewCell (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, mono, vertical-alignment

I use just UITableViewCell.

It occur only in real device(version 3.1.2) and in simulator(version 3.1.2) doesn't have any problem.

Thank you for your advice.

Here is my problem image

[image: http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?00252c143c.png]

Comment: What do you mean by vertical text alignment? You want the text to be in the middle of the cell?

Comment: yes, I need text in the middle of the cell.

I don't know why occur only in real device?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a bug to me, but a workaround is to set cell.detailTextLabel.text = @""; if you don't want any text to appear on the right side of the cell. 
Or
If there are empty rows try filling it with @""

```
switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
        cell.textLabel.text = @"";
        break;
    case 1:
                [cell addSubview:label];
        break;
    case 2:
        cell.textLabel.text = @"";
        break;
```

}

The 0th row and 2nd row don't have any data in them. Hence filled it with @"".

Comment: It's still make me wonder. why it's occur only in my device? In SDK doesn't have problem.